# A lot of bloat in system postresql tables

Tags: postgresql, vacuum

I have PgSql 13.7 at Amazon RDS, this is production, so can't stop everything there.
I run into strange behaviour with dead tuples, there is a lot of bloat in system tables. For example:

```
pg_attribute: Live tuples=823, Dead tuples=750939   
pg_statistic: Live=776 Dead=528366  
pg_depend: Live=525 Dead=219947
```

Running vacuum on that tables doesn't clean anything:

```
> SELECT txid_current();
38159688
```

```
> VACUUM FULL VERBOSE pg_statistic;
INFO:  vacuuming “pg_catalog.pg_statistic”
INFO:  “pg_statistic”: found 0 removable, 527834 nonremovable row versions in 37988 pages
DETAIL:  527058 dead row versions cannot be removed yet, oldest xmin: 37231295
```

Same with autovacuum, many-many dead row versions, that cannot be removed yet.

I've checked, I have no long running transactions, all of them finishes in 5-10 seconds.
A have several replication slots, but none of them are holding transaction number (xmin=null for evety slot)
There is no long living locks in pg_locks also.
And also I see many pg_toast_* and pg_temp_* tables. My best guess, that they cannot be cleared until that dead tuples in system tables are exist.

Any ideas, what next step should I do find a root of a problem?

I did manual VACUUM, I've looked for locks etc

Comment: This might be a better question for DBA.SE. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/160979/vacuum-verbose-outputs-nonremovable-dead-row-versions-cannot-be-removed-yet

Answer (score 1):

Catalog tables are just like normal tables in that respect. There is [something that blocks `VACUUM`'s progress](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/reasons-why-vacuum-wont-remove-dead-rows/). Apart from open transactions and replication slots, which are the most frequent causes, it could also be

- prepared transactions that were not committed or rolled back
- a long running transaction on a standby server with `hot_standby_feedback = on`